# Extending std namespace with backported code

Tags: c++, boost, std, undefined-behavior, tr1

**Some background:**

Extending `namespace std` is undefined-behaviour(UB) unless it is a template specialization [[1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std)]:

> It is undefined behavior to add declarations or definitions to
>   namespace std or to any namespace nested within std, with a few
>   exceptions noted below

There also questions on SO which also say it's an UB and a bad idea [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629249/inject-namespace-experimental-to-std/34629714), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185182/extending-namespace-std-with-backported-types-and-templates-from-newer-c-stand)].

We use [`boost::tr1`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_tr1.html) on platforms that don't have `tr1` support (e.g., WinCE, WM). Boost does exactly this: injects its own implementation into `std::tr1` if `tr1` is not provided.

For example in [`boost/tr1/memory.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/tr1/memory.hpp):

```
namespace std{ namespace tr1{ 
   using ::boost::bad_weak_ptr;
   using ::boost::shared_ptr;
   ...
} }
```

**My questions are:**

- Does this mean that it is UB if `boost::tr1` is used with non-tr1 compilers?
- Alternatively, is it okay to inject backports into `std` as long as developer makes sure that backported functionality is unavailable?
- If it is okay, can one take it one step further and inject `boost::tr1` into `std` instead of `std::tr1`?

Comment: Most of the UB comes from the fact that an implementation is allowed to already add specializations and additional overloads to namespace std. If you do that too, there will be conflicts. Boost just *might* have their tricks sanctioned by the compiler manufacturers, in which case it is implementation defined instead of UB.

Comment: Just... don't do it. Put stuff in namespace `mystd` or something instead. Then you won't have to deal with any of these questions.

Comment: @Barry it seems so. I am now leaning towards `std_` solution

Comment: If the idea is to *backport* then I'd say you count as an implementor by definition and thus you are implicitly allowed to do the stuff in namespace std; the question is moot otherwise as the alternative is simply nonfunctional backports: how would you make code in function signatures or template parameters that uses eg.: ``typename = std::enable_if<....>`` use a enable_if located somewhere else instead? There's no ``using`` in signatures. That's just one case. As for whether it's UB, "do as the compiler does" and you'll at most be as much UB as them.